# Angular Reactive Form after RemveAt deleting a item, the new item will be created automatically

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I implement an angular app with reactive form, this is a dynamica form, which can add a item dynamically, after adding, the add button will be disappeared and a delete button will be created automatically.

my goal is that after deleting, the add button will be visible again.

I have debugged, I found after removing item, the function addNewContact will be called. I don't kown why.

the code lokks just like this:

```
get contactFormData(): FormArray {
    return this.form.controls.contact as FormArray;
  }

public addNewContact(): void {
      this.contactFormData.push(this.fb.group({
        name: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }, 
                              [Validators.required])
        
      }));

      //this.canAddMoreContact = false;

  }
public removeContact(indexWillBeRemoved: number): void {
  
    this.contactFormData.removeAt(indexWillBeRemoved);
    this.canAddMoreContact = true;
  
  }
```

and html code :

```
<ng-container >

    hier is a form

     <div *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.type.disabled" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary"
          matTooltip="Remove Contact"
          (click)="removeContact(contactFormIndex)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <div *ngIf="canAddMoreContact">
      <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" matTooltip="Add Contact" (click)="addNewContact()">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but it was not working, when I commented this.canAddMoreContact = true; it worked.

I don't know what is problem...

any solutions?

Comment: In the add you have `canAddMoreContact` but in the remove you have  `canAddContact` might that causing the issue of add button not visible!

Comment: sure, I have edited my code. but what I can see by debugging is, this add method will be also called after removing...

Comment: Can you check the call stack in developer tools after removing contact?